# PHP Curl doesn't work when tried to get contents of a specific domain

Tags: php, curl

PHP Curl doesn't work when tried to get contents of a specific domain.

The specific domain is 'www.net4winners.com.br', it works with every domain but not with this domain, it always returns: 'object not found' in curl output.

PHP Code of this test:

```
<?php
function run_curl($url,$p=null)
    {
        $ch = curl_init();
        $options = array(
        CURLOPT_URL => $url,
        CURLOPT_HEADER => 0,
        CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST => 0,
        CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => 0,
        CURLOPT_USERAGENT => "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.0; en-US; rv:1.9.2) Gecko/20100115 Firefox/3.6 (.NET CLR 3.5.30729)",
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => 1,
        CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => 1
        );
        if($p != null)
        {
            $options[CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST] = "POST";
            $options[CURLOPT_POST] = 1;
            $options[CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS] = $p;
        }

        curl_setopt_array($ch,$options);

        $resultado = curl_exec($ch);

        if($resultado) { return $resultado; } else { return curl_error($ch); }

        curl_close($ch);
    }
    $out = run_curl('http://www.net4winners.com.br/');
    echo $out;
?>
```

could someone help me please?

Thanks.

Comment: No problem running that script on my connection.

Comment: if i run it on my connection it works but if i put it in locaweb server it won't work but it only happens with this domain 'net4.com.br'.

Comment: So what is your problem if it is working for you? Are you able to visit this 'locaweb server' in a browser successfully?

Comment: i mean if i run this code in locaweb server, locaweb is host, i have my website hosted by locaweb.

Answer (score 1):

It's not working because the server is checking for the existence of certain headers which are not sent by cURL. Based on my testing, the one that's missing in your case is *Accept-Language*.

Try adding the following to your `$options` array:

```
CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array('Accept-Language: en-us')
```

**Example:**

```
<?php

$ch = curl_init('http://www.net4winners.com.br/');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_7_2) AppleWebKit/534.51.22 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/5.1.1 Safari/534.51.22');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
    'Accept-Language: en-us'
));
curl_exec($ch);
```

Comment: it didn't help but now i'm getting this error: Internal Server Error UID of script "/home/httpd/html/index.php" is smaller than min_uid
suPHP 0.6.3

Comment: That error sounds unrelated. Is that error on your server or is that what you're getting back from cURL? If it's on your server, make sure that the file is owned by the proper user. Sounds like a permission issue.

Comment: cuz i'm doing echo in curl output.

Comment: i figured out that if i try to get 'http://www.net4winners.com.br/' it returns 'object not found' but if try to get 'http://www.net4winners.com.br/index.php' it returns this 'internal server error'. strange

Comment: Right but it could be your server that's returning that error. Can you remove the `echo` line and see if it's still happening? If so, the problem isn't the `echo` line but your own PHP file. It sounds like Apache (or the web server) serving the file doesn't want to allow that file to be executed because the user ID of the owner of the file is less than the minimum allowed.

Comment: this error is from curl output cuz i removed the echo and i get no errors.

Comment: but if i try to get files from any other server it works fine.